# Python Poetry: how to specify platform-specific dependency alternatives?

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-ldap, python-poetry

**Some background:** 
The project I'm working on uses `python-ldap` library. Since we are a mixed-OS development team (some use Linux, some macOS and some Windows), I'm trying to make the project build on all environments. Unfortunately, `python-ldap` is not officially supported for Windows, but there are [unofficial wheels maintained by Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap). I've tested the wheel file and it works fine.

**The problem:** how do I tell Poetry to use the wheel on Windows and the official `python-ldap` package on Linux and macOS?

I've tried multiple things, including using multiple constraint dependencies and [markers](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers):

```
python-ldap = [
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'linux'", version = "*" },
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'win32'", path="lib/python_ldap-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" }
```

... but, judging from the `poetry.lock` file, it seems markers are then merged and just determine whether the library should be installed **at all**:

```
[[package]]
category = "main"
description = "Python modules for implementing LDAP clients"
marker = "sys_platform == \"linux\" or sys_platform == \"win32\""
name = "python-ldap"
```

Is there another way of dealing with platform-specific dependencies in Poetry?

Comment: I have the same problem. Currently I'm using commented out lines of dependencies, but it's far from ideal. Please tell me if you found a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The best way to do this is the use the `--platform` option with the `poetry add` command. For installing `faiss` on both Mac (`faiss-cpu` with no CUDA GPU support) and Linux (`faiss-gpu` with GPU/CUDA support available) you run the following commands:

```sh
# Add each package to your project
poetry add faiss-gpu --platform linux
poetry add faiss-cpu --platform darwin

# Thereafter just install
poetry install
```

As mentioned above, you can do this in the `pyproject.toml` file as described in the other answer, but the CLI is best. Be sure to `poetry update` if you edit `pyproject.toml` directly:

```py
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
faiss-cpu = {version = "^1.7.1", platform = "darwin"}
faiss-gpu = {version = "^1.7.1", platform = "linux"}
```

Holla!

Comment: Why is using the CLI better than editing pyproject.toml directly?

Comment: @burnpanck The arguments are that it prevents you from making a mistake, and that it updates the lock file and virtualenv automatically, but it's perfectly common to edit it manually, as well. Whatever works best for you.

Comment: This does answer the questions, unfortunately. The package names are different in the answer, but the same in the original question.

Comment: @bayer I'm not clear on what I should do to improve it - can you edit this or explain? Oh, the `faiss` stuff. Yeah, that came from my code. It seemed a clearer answer? I can add his code.

Comment: "The problem: how do I tell Poetry to use the wheel on Windows and the official python-ldap package on Linux and macOS?" No current answer shows this exact scenario.

Comment: This does not answer the question because the package names are different in your example. How would you express this platform dependency with packages having the same name?

Comment: I believe the same thing works?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `platform` keyword

```
python-ldap = [
    { version = '*', platform = 'linux' },
]
```

[Source](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/984#issuecomment-475881162)

Comment: Even better, such as for `faiss-cpu` vs `faiss-gpu` - let the CLI do it for you.

`poetry add faiss-gpu --platform linux`
`poetry add faiss-cpu --platform darwin`

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. This only lists `linux`. As far as I can tell, there's no `windows` platform.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Poetry does not support well platform-specific dependency alternatives when one of the constrain contains a `version` tag unfortunately. For your solution to work, you would have to specify a `path` or `url` tag to a local or distant wheel instead.

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924920/how-to-specify-platform-specific-dependences-with-poetry) with PyTorch dependencies and I was able to solve it by changing this:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
torch = [
    {platform = "linux", url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118/torch-2.0.1%2Bcu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl"},
    {platform = "darwin", version = "2.0.1"},
]
```

to this:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
torch = [
    {platform = "darwin", url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.0.1-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl"},
    {platform = "linux", url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118/torch-2.0.1%2Bcu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl"},
]
```

Notice the Linux specification which now links directly to the wheel file.