# poetry install different package version based on extras

Tags: python, python-poetry

Using python-poetry, I would like to install different package versions based on the extras that I pass during the installation. E.g. I would like to

```
# when extra == 'a', install numpy == 1.20.0
$ poetry install -E a
# when extra == 'b', install numpy == 1.19.0
$ poetry install -E b
```

I tried it with the following toml file

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "demo-poetry"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["tenticon"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
numpy = [
    { version = "1.20.0", markers = "extra == 'a'", optional = true},
    { version = "1.19.0", markers = "extra == 'b'", optional = true}
]

[tool.poetry.extras]
a = [ "numpy" ]
b = [ "numpy" ]

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

but when I do `$ poetry install -E a` I get

```
  SolverProblemError

  Because demo-poetry depends on both numpy (1.20.0) and numpy (1.19.0), version solving failed.
```

My poetry version is 1.1.6

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Because no one  prevent you from install extra `a` and extra `b` together. And poetry checks that the dependency resolution works in every case. Is there a way to prevent installing both extras in `setuptools`?

Comment: I tried adding different versions of a package using dependency groups, which are available since the pre-release 1.2.0a2 (https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.2.0a2). However, it did not work. As indicated by @finswimmer, the groups are not mutually exclusive, and poetry checks that the dependency resolution works in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Poetry extras](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras) are sets of packages (e.g. `a = ["numpy", "scipy"]`) that can be optionally installed together with the main dependencies (`poetry install -E a`). When installing or specifying poetry-built packages, the extras defined in the toml file can be activated as described in [PEP-508 definition of extras](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#extras). Thus, the dependencies required by the `a` extra could be installed using `pip install demo-poetry[a]` (just like any other [pip extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474931/what-is-extra-in-pypi-dependency)).

It is indeed possible to use [environment markers](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers) as install conditions for dependencies (see [list of PEP-508 environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers)). However, at the time of writing the environment marker `extra` is [not returned by the relevant function](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/1.1.12/poetry/utils/env.py#L1321) `get_marker_env()`, and therefore it is ignored as install constraint. The PEP-508 documentation also notes that the `extra` variable is special, and that there is no current specification for it.

Neither using extras nor groups (from the [pre-release 1.2.0a2](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.2.0a2)) was sufficient in order to achieve the expected results. In this regard, I think the comment from @finswimmer is correct: groups are not mutually exclusive, but poetry checks that the dependency resolution works in every case.

The closest I could get to an acceptable solution was by defining conditions based on the python version, or based [on the platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052866/python-poetry-how-to-specify-platform-specific-dependency-alternatives). Note that these conditions should always be mutually exclusive, otherwise you will get an error.

For instance, if you have the following `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "demo-poetry"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["vreyespue"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
numpy = [
    { version = "1.19.0", python = "~3.7"},
    { version = "1.20.0", python = "~3.9"}
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

You could install different versions of `numpy` in different environments:

```
$ poetry env use 3.7
  Using virtualenv: /***/demo-poetry-***-py3.7

$ poetry install
  Installing numpy (1.19.0)

$ poetry env use 3.9
  Using virtualenv: /***/demo-poetry-***-py3.9

$ poetry install
  Installing numpy (1.20.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bothered me for internal development, and while it was extremely frustrating since neither `poetry` nor `cleo` offer any documentation on their SDK, I finally managed to create a plugin for this ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/poet-plugin/), [git](https://github.com/idantene/poet-exclusive-groups-plugin)).

The idea is that with this plugin, you can have non-mutual exclusive definitions in groups, and when using the `--without` or `--only` flags, the relevant groups are dropped from dependency parsing. The plugin needs to be installed prior to any such group definition.

Installation via `poetry add poet-plugin` (if starting from an empty, clean project, without such dependencies), or then via:

```bash
poetry shell
pip install poet-plugin
```

I have not battle-tested this, but it works nicely for our use case with e.g.

```bash
poetry install --only prod
poetry install --only dev
poetry install --without dev
poetry install --without prod
```

Feedback and updates etc are welcome, hope this momentarily resolves this issue for some of us out there.